# How do to iteratively call a method without waiting for response from method in c# .Net 4.5.1?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

First off I apologize for terrible wording of that question...here's the scenario:

I built a WEB API method that receives a ProductID and then uploads that products images to Amazon S3. This part is working just fine.

I am now trying to get a console app running that will grab a range of ProductIDs and loop through them, calling the API method, and not wait for the results...

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I suppose another caveat would be to not eat up all the resources on the machine running the console app...so maybe a thread cap?

**UPDATE (This still seems to be synchronous):**

```
class Program
{
    async static void DoUpload(int itemid)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting #:" + itemid);
        Thread.Sleep(2000); //Simulates long call to API
        Console.WriteLine("Finishing #:" + itemid);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            DoUpload(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make asynchronous versions of your web API methods and use those methods. If that's not possible, call the methods from separate tasks/threads.

Comment: Have you looked at the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/DeveloperGuide/sdk-net-async-api.html) for the asynchronous APIs using C#?

Comment: Don't create `async void` methods unless you're sure that you have to, and that it's the correct option at the time.  Usually it's not.  You should almost always be returning a `Task` instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple easy ways to do this.

I'd recommend using [Parallels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693(v=vs.110).aspx).  It makes the most optimized use of your environments many threads/cores.  For your example, you'd simply do something like this:

```
var status = Parallel.For(0, 20, DoUpload);

while (!status.IsCompleted)
{
    //Do something while you wait
}
```

The other method would be to use Tasks, and send each call as a separate task.  Be careful with this approach though because you could overload the system with pending tasks if you have too many iterations.

```
List<Tasks> tasks = new List<Tasks>();

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => DoUpload(i));

    tasks.Add(task);
}

//wait for completion of all tasks
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not recommend using Parallel.For. It does not give an satisfactory control of parallelism (you probably don't want to hammer away hundrades of requests which will start to timeout) also it requires unnecessary context switching.

Threads/cores isn't the limiting factor in case http requests.

In the example change

```
Thread.Sleep(2000)
```

to

```
await Task.Delay(2000)
```

and when using real web api calls

```
await httpClient.PostAsync(...)
```

also remember to wait in Main

```
Console.ReadLine() // or something more sophisticated
```

otherwise the program will terminate before the calls have been made.

Then to control the level of parallelism I think the easiest solution is to use a Semaphore to count the number of outstanding calls, waiting in the main loop for the semaphore to be signaled again before issuing new requests.